# Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the id from an url like this: Id is positive int.
And I to try do this with regexp:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer/3/'
url.match('///d/')
```

But this pattern doesn't work.
Please help me.

Comment: `\d` is a digit, not `/d`.

Comment: @WalterTross I know which is seems RTFM but as I see you don't read it too because you answer is wrong too

Comment: @Denis: What Wooble says is absolutely correct, `\d` matches any digit. Your response on the other hand is very rude.

Comment: Be carefully I don't argue with Wooble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regexp gets the number at the end of your url: /3/ -> 3

```
/\/([0-9]+)\/$/
```

Comment: url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer/3/';
url.match('/\/([0-9]+)\/$/'); return null

Comment: @Denis: You misunderstand. The `/` on the beginning and end are for placing a literal regexp in code. You do NOT put this in quotes. `url = '127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer/3/'; url.match(/\/([0-9]+)\/$/);` returns `["/3/", "3"]`

Comment: many thx, lal, I starting goes mad because all my regexps do not want to work ))) javascript ...

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this would be sufficient:

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/customer/3/';
var id;
url = url.split('/');
for (var x = 0; x < url.length; x++) {
    if (url[x] === 'customer') {
        id = parseInt(url[x + 1], 10);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: looks weird, I need more practical solve with regexp

Comment: @Denis: What's weird about it? Looks straight-forward to me.

Comment: I just need a positive integer between two slashes

Comment: @Denis This would return the id as a string. Perform parseInt(url[x + 1]) if you want it to be a number

Comment: Man, I don't offend you but your solve is looks like reinventing the wheel, but anyway thx for you help

Comment: @Denis Don't use it if you don't like it. It's simple and it allows you to look at the rest of the tokens in your url if you wish to.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you always want the last digit at the end of the string, I'd go for this:

```
(\d)(?:\/)$
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/ijIpRkQD1N).

Or, if you want to make the trailing `/` optional, you could do:

```
(\d)(?:\/)?$
```

See [here](http://rubular.com/r/3O8vHGoHqM)

Comment: all these staff is return null it's just doesn't work

Comment: @Denis: In English we say "thank you". But it does work. Your problem is, as Friederike S above pointed out, you keep treating regex literals as if they are strings. They are not. They do not need to be (and shouldn't be) enclosed in quotes. You need `url.match(/(\d)(?:\/)$/)`.

Comment: OK, I understооd my error you solve is work nice too, I confused by javascript how it is possible pass to function I even don't know how this is a called ... plain text without quotes.

Comment: @Denis: Ok, it's fine. It may look like plain text, but it isn't. Just as enclosing some characters in quotes makes it a string, enclosing it between `/` makes it a regex literal. It's a shortcut for the `new RegExp("abc")` syntax and avoids a lot of escaping that can be a real pain with the `new RegEx` syntax. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, I will carefully read this article.